# Azure Search: Wildcard search in combination with CustomAnalyzer

Tags: c#, azure, search, asp.net-core

```
QueryType = Simple
SearchMode = All

var myField = new Field("field", DataType.String)
{
    IsRetrievable = false,
    IsSearchable = true,
    Analyzer = "myAnalyzer"
};
fields.Add(myField);

var index = new Index()
{
    Name = IndexName,
    Fields = fields,
    Tokenizers = new List<Tokenizer>()
    {
        new PatternTokenizer()
        {
            Name = "myPatternTokenizer",
            Pattern = "[\\s]"
        }
    },
    Analyzers = new List<Analyzer>()
    {
        new CustomAnalyzer()
        {
            Name = "myAnalyzer",
            Tokenizer = "myPatternTokenizer"
        }
    }
};
```

Why does the wildcard-search doesn't work anymore in combination with a CustomAnalyzer + PatternTokenizer (Pattern="\s")? Without CustomAnalyzer it worked fine!

**Without CustomAnalyzer:**

Value: "Azure"

Search "Az*"

Match: true

**With CustomAnalyzer + PatternTokenizer:**

Value: "Azure"

Search "Az*"

Match: false // Why???